# Is there a `sty2dtx` for LaTeX3 syntax?

Tags: package-writing, expl3, documentation

[`sty2dtx`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/sty2dtx) is a CLI tool to convert a commented style file into a Documented TeX file (`dtx`).
It was written and works wonderfully for LaTeX2e packages, but `expl3` offers a lot of happy times for package authors.

Unfortunately, `expl3` also brings with it some hitherto unconventional syntax, such as underscores and colons in control sequences.
`sty2dtx` doesn't seem to like that, (or more appropriately, `ltxdoc` doesn't).

Is there a descendant of `sty2dtx` (or an undocumented option, perhaps) that works with LaTeX3 syntax?

Comment: If the only issue is document class, did you try using the script then using `l3doc` in place of `ltxdoc`? I'd ad that `sty2dtx` always worries me a bit: the thing about a proper `.dtx` is it's meant to include some explanation, which is not really easy to automate.

Comment: @JosephWright Actually, I'm having a hard time *finding* the documentation; `texdoc l3doc` just brings me to the `expl3` introduction.  I've nothing to compare it against :(

Comment: I usually use `sty2dtx` to create the skeleton file that I then flesh out with the actual documentation.  Since I still don't fully understand the format, learning by example this way helps a ton.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @TeXnician I don't think I ever did, no :-/